# Docker swarm nodes in the same overlay network can't see each other

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have a weird problem in my swarm, docker services inside of the same network can't communicate, I get the following error when I try to communicate between them:

```
could not translate host name "dev_db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have been investigating if they are on the same network and according to inspect they are in the same Network overlay:

```
docker service inspect dev_slavedb
[
    {
        "ID": "flcwn7p17lgy6f9ad89iqas0e",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 68009
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2018-01-06T00:33:22.602060695Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2018-01-06T00:33:22.603561612Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "dev_slavedb",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "postgres:latest@sha256:3f4441460029e12905a5d447a3549ae2ac13323d045391b0cb0cf8b48ea17463",
                    "Env": [
                        "POSTGRES_USER=mydatabase",
                        "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mydatabase"
                    ],
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Source": "slave_postgres",
                            "Target": "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
                        }
                    ],
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {}
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Constraints": [
                        "node.hostname==swarm02"
                    ],
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "hh8zmhc9gx0p9iwukozo31dgs"
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 5432,
                        "PublishedPort": 5432,
                        "PublishMode": "host"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 5432,
                        "PublishedPort": 5432,
                        "PublishMode": "host"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 5432,
                    "PublishedPort": 5432,
                    "PublishMode": "host"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "hh8zmhc9gx0p9iwukozo31dgs",
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.4/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]





docker service inspect dev_db
[
    {
        "ID": "jqwmzoe57lonbr0wwnp262x9i",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 68001
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2018-01-06T00:30:50.284998521Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2018-01-06T00:30:50.285963303Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "dev_db",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "postgres:latest@sha256:3f4441460029e12905a5d447a3549ae2ac13323d045391b0cb0cf8b48ea17463",
                    "Env": [
                        "POSTGRES_USER=mydatabase",
                        "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mydatabase"
                    ],
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Source": "postgres",
                            "Target": "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
                        }
                    ],
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {}
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Constraints": [
                        "node.hostname==swarm01"
                    ],
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "hh8zmhc9gx0p9iwukozo31dgs"
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 5432,
                        "PublishedPort": 5432,
                        "PublishMode": "host"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 5432,
                        "PublishedPort": 5432,
                        "PublishMode": "host"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 5432,
                    "PublishedPort": 5432,
                    "PublishMode": "host"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "hh8zmhc9gx0p9iwukozo31dgs",
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.2/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Even when I try to use their VIPs (10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.4) I also get the same error. I don't know how to troubleshoot this, any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Can clarify more about what you created ? like a Leader and how many slaves, i know it is visible reading your posted question but i want to get to the bottom of what exactly you are trying to do and why it is not letting you.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the proper firewall ports open on each Swarm node to let the other nodes in, otherwise things like DNS and other communications won't happen:

https://www.bretfisher.com/docker-swarm-firewall-ports/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest trying to create the Overlay Network yourself to make sure it actually works. Once the overlay network is created you can add all the nodes to a subnet if necessary and access them in that fashion or through a more complicated route you can simply create ssh channels between them to make sure you can control the communication.

1. Here is how you create the Overlay Network

[Overlay-Network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/#customize-an-overlay-network)

Comment: The overlay network was created by myself using your link that you recommended. The nodes are part of that overlay network as you can see in the details inside of the inspect part I was showing.

Comment: can you show how you created the overlay network ? like exact command line code...